# Information about っちょ noun suffix

Tags: meaning, suffixes, formality

I recently encountered the suffix っちょ after a noun in a manga. According to [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87), it is a suffix used after a noun or the root of an adjective and which means "person who is/thing that is".

Since it is the first time I encounter this suffix, I would like to know how common it is and what kind of nuance it adds. How formal is it? Also, is it regional or used everywhere in Japan? Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to include the manga phrase and context?

Answer (score 2):

This is a suffix similar in purpose to English -ling or -ie, but it attaches to only a few words. Perhaps words understood by the general public are only 先っちょ, 横っちょ and 太っちょ. Some dictionaries also list 尼っちょ and ちびっちょ as examples, but I have never heard them. It may also appear in someone's nicknames (can be derogatory; a recent example is ホラッチョ). It is not used in formal writings.

Comment: ガキンチョ！，，，，，，，，，，

Comment: おお、確かに！,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: @DariusJahandarie What is ガキンチョ?